# Javascript(Eslint) Function never Used

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have been using Eslint for some time. I have defined a function which takes user input and assignes it to variable. The function is called in HTML on button click. I have an error in js that this function is never used. I know that this is not a problem at all. Just trying to write correct code from the start.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want this to be an error stopping you from starting the application, set the eslint `no-unused-vars` rule to `off` or `warn` in your eslint configuration file (`eslintrc.js` or similar). For example:

```
module.exports = {

  ...

  rules: {
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',
  },
};
```

Note that in order for this to work you have to restart the application.

Comment: Thank you, for your comment.